# Selected Tab highlighted until the user not clicked to the another tab in vuejs

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

**I need to highlight the current tab until user can not clicked to the next tab. Hover can only help to highlight the tab but once chooses the any other things hover tab gone.**

*For example i clicked to the categories tab, it will highlighted but once chooses any product inside the categories then hover removed*

 Can anyone help me how to do that?

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div class="navbar w-100 is-white is-fixed-bottom bottom-navbar is-hidden-desktop is-mobile">
      <div class="nav-highlight">
        <router-link to="/">
          <div class="has-text-centered column is-3">
            <div><img class="image-resize" src="@/assets/home.jpeg" alt="home icon" /></div>
            <div class="s-small f-size">Home</div>
          </div>
        </router-link>
      </div>

      <div class="nav-highlight">
        <router-link to="/categories">
          <div class="has-text-centered column is-3">
            <div><img class="image-resize" src="@/assets/products.jpeg" alt="product icon" /></div>
            <div class="s-small f-size">Products</div>
          </div>
        </router-link>
      </div>

      <div class="nav-highlight">
        <router-link to="/wish-list">
          <div class="has-text-centered column is-3">
            <div><img class="image-resize" src="@/assets/wishlist.jpeg" alt="wishlist icon" /></div>
            <div class="s-small f-size">Wislist</div>
          </div>
        </router-link>
      </div>

      <div class="nav-highlight">
        <router-link to="/redeem-point">
          <div class="has-text-centered column is-3">
            <div><img class="image-resize" src="@/assets/redeem.jpeg" alt="redeem icon" /></div>
            <div class="s-small f-size">Redeem Points</div>
          </div>
        </router-link>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'FooterNavBar',
  components: {},
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.bottom-navbar {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background: white;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.nav-highlight{
  width: 25%;
}
 .nav-highlight :hover {
    background-color: rgb(194, 193, 193);
} 
.image-resize {
  width: 180px;
  height: 26px;
}
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

This next example works even if you have children in your routes.

I'm using your categories as an example. What you need to do is to check when the route changes and what route is active. For example, if you use `this.$routes.name` or `this.$routes.path` you have access to the current route name and the current route path. All you need to do is to verify if the current route matches the nav tab.

so your HTML should look like this (you just need to use the same logic to the others)

```html
     <div :class="$route.path.includes('/categories') ? 'nav-highlight active' : 'nav-highlight'">
        <router-link to="/categories">
          <div class="has-text-centered column is-3">
            <div><img class="image-resize" src="@/assets/products.jpeg" alt="product icon" /></div>
            <div class="s-small f-size">Products</div>
          </div>
        </router-link>
      </div>
```

Your css:

```css
    .nav-highlight{
      width: 25%;
    }
    .nav-highligth.active {
      background-color: rgb(194, 193, 193);
    }
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for your reply, i added your solution but haven't saw any changes in my file.

Comment: I have done the typo mistake in css class that's why it was not working previously. Thanks, It's working now.

Comment: What in case if my child route not matched with the parent for example- /categories/sub-category not like this?  In that case is it still possible any way to highlight it ? @Vanishdark

Comment: requirement is: Categories section will be highlighted until and unless user not chooses to the another three of them.

Comment: Hey swaying sorry for late reply. Yes it a way to do it. Let me do a quick search in some of my code. I have somewhere an an example that applies to that,

Comment: A quick solution and easy is to split the path by / and check the first position is the one you want. Something like $route.path.split(’/’)[0] = ‘category’